# All of my invites are gone

Tags: ingress

I've just realized that all of my invites have been zeroed. Is this related to the network wide problems which occured yesterday or is it something else?

Did someone else experience the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *appears* to be a bug that was introduced in version 1,74 (not confirmed, simply noticed there).

You can go to Ingress's [Intel](http://ingress.com/intel) website and use the **Recruit** button in the top right corner, you'll be able to recruit new agents and you'll see the correct number of invites you have remaining.

[image: Ingress invites by Ingress's Intel website]

Note that the **Recruit** button does not appear in their mobile version.

**Edit**

I checked the status of this last night and it appears as if the invites are back in the app, let's hope they stay there and that everyone has it back.

Comment: @Montag451 Very strange indeed. You're welcome :)